# Is there a way to disable multiple objects selected in the outliner?

Tags: interface, selection-tools, outliner

So I've been looking for a way to make blender behave just like any other software ever - one LMB with no modifiers should select 1 item and deselect everything else, right? Well, instead, at least in my case, it does this:

[image]

As if I'm holding CTRL.

I checked both my 2.93 and 3.0.0 versions. But, of course, I imported my preferences from 2.93 so it was inherited if it's a setting I unwittingly changed.

Comment: Yeah, that's strange. I can't reproduce it if I try

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I've just installed a fresh 2.93.4 version and it doesn't have this. My 3.0.0 does though. I think it's a bug or something. It even doesn't obey selection sync.

Comment: I encountered this once, but restarting Blender helped. Might be a bug or some obscure shortcut :)

Comment: @JachymMichal thanks, yeah. Installing the latest alpha version fixed this. Idk if this was a bug or a weird hotkey toggle. It's gone now and I couldn't be happier!